# How to detect ESCape keypress in Python?

Tags: python, windows, escaping, keypress

I am running a process in a command window (Windows 7, Python 3.1) where I would like the user to abort the process by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.  However, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't appear to do anything, the loop never breaks. I have also tried running the script from within my IDE (Wing), but again, the loop cannot be interrupted.

The following is a stripped-down version of my proof-of-concept test...

```
import msvcrt
import time

aborted = False

for time_remaining in range(10,0,-1):
    # First of all, check if ESCape was pressed
    if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch()==chr(27):
        aborted = True
        break

    print(str(time_remaining))       # so I can see loop is working
    time.sleep(1)                    # delay for 1 second
#endfor timing loop

if aborted:
    print("Program was aborted")
else:
    print("Program was not aborted")

time.sleep(5)  # to see result in command window before it disappears!
```

If anyone could tell me where I might be going wrong I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python 3 strings are unicode and, therefore, must be encoded to bytes for comparison.  Try this test:

```
if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch() == chr(27).encode():
    aborted = True
    break
```

Or this test:

```
if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch().decode() == chr(27):
    aborted = True
    break
```

Or this test:

```
if msvcrt.kbhit() and ord(msvcrt.getch()) == 27:
    aborted = True
    break
```

Answer (score 6):

You should really strip down more, like this one below:

```
>>> import msvcrt
>>> ch = msvcrt.getch()
# Press esc
>>> ch
b'\x1b'
>>> chr(27)
'\x1b'
>>> ch == chr(27)
False
```

So here is the problem: `msvcrt.getch()` returns [`bytes`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/functions.html#bytes), `chr(27)` returns `string`. In Python 3 they are two distinct types, so the "`==`" part will never work, and the `if` statement will always be evaluated as `False`.

The solution should be obvious to you.

[More](http://diveintopython3.org/strings.html#byte-arrays) about strings vs bytes, from the book Dive into Python 3.

The interactive console is very useful for debugging, try use it more :)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need encode, decode, chr, ord, ....

```
if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch() == b'\x1b':
```

or if you'd like to see "27" in the code somewhere:

```
if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch()[0] == 27:
```

Comment: Being brought-up on ASCII values, I prefer the 2nd example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Python 2/3 compatible code:

```
import time, sys

ESC = '\x1b'
PY3K = sys.version_info >= (3,)
if PY3K:
    from msvcrt import kbhit, getwch as _getch
else:
    from msvcrt import kbhit, getch as _getch
while not kbhit() or _getch() != ESC:
    print(time.asctime())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Code parts are taken from [`pager`](https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-pager/src/tip/pager.py) module with more stuff inside.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a different key to test if it's not just that key?

Did you also try the examples [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20200720202438/http://effbot.org/librarybook/msvcrt.htm) to see if they worked?

Comment: Hi Corey,  tried the examples suggested and started getting "b'\x1b'" output, which thanks to other posters here I now know is the bytestring version, which has to be converted to unicode.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

import cv2 as cv

a = cv.waitkey(0)

if (a == 27 or ord('esc') == 27):
aborted = True
break