# How to set a key to close a program

Tags: python, windows, keyboard-events, key-bindings

I'm attempting to write my own Auto-Clicker program as a side-project (I'm a new programmer).

And I have tried looking into to how to bind a key to kill a program but that only led to tkinter and I am not looking to use tkinter (at least right now)

```
import win32api
import win32con
import sys

def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0,  0)

for n in range(100000):
    click(100, 450)
```

So what exactly would I add in to this current script so that I can bind let's say the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to kill this program?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137238/how-to-detect-escape-keypress-in-python