# terminating a python loop

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I made a program that reads pixels from a camera. I have used a while loop. But I can't close the program from terminal without pressing 'Cltrl + C'. I want to close the program using ESC button ( ASCII 27). I tried the following code, which is not working. Any help would be appreciated

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
   _, frame = cap.read()

   redimage = frame[:,:,2]
   print(redimage)

   k = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
   if k == 27:
      break
```

Comment: try `if k == chr(27): break`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if k == chr(27):
   break
```

Answer (score 0):

`cv.waitKey(1)` is working for `opencv` `gui` only. You can't capture keyboard events in console with this function.

So, you can change your code to show the frame that you are reading from the camera.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
   _, frame = cap.read()
   redimage = frame[:,:,2]
   cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
   print(redimage)
   k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
   if k == 27:
      break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You can find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137238/how-to-detect-escape-keypress-in-python) a way to capture keyboard events in console.