# Using 'esc' to close PySimpleGUI window

Tags: python, user-interface, msvcrt, pysimplegui

I have a PySimpleGUI window that I want to maximise, eventually without a title bar. I want to use the 'esc' key to close the window.

Here's my (simplified) code:

```
import msvcrt
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text(size=(40, 1), font=("Arial", (32)), justification='left', key='-TEXT-')]]
window = sg.Window(title="Window", layout=layout, grab_anywhere=True, finalize = True, no_titlebar=False)

window.maximize()

escape = False

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch() == chr(27).encode():
        escape = True
    else:
        ecape = False

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel' or escape == True:
        break

window.close()
```

The close button works fine - but pressing escape does nothing.

I've tried several of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137238/how-to-detect-escape-keypress-in-python), but with no luck.

What's going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Pretty sure `getch` gets input from command-line, not your pysimplegui window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

As @knosmos pointed out, `getch` is only for the command line. Adding `return_keyboard_events=True` and `event == 'Escape:27'` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Bind event `"<Escape>"` to window to generate an event,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text(size=(40, 1), font=("Arial", (32)), justification='left', key='-TEXT-')]]
window = sg.Window(title="Window", layout=layout, grab_anywhere=True, finalize = True, no_titlebar=False)
window.maximize()
window.bind("<Escape>", "-ESCAPE-")

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "-ESCAPE-"):
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```